# Can a strategy be implemented as a nested member class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is it okay to have a strategy implemented as a non-static inner class or is it considered a bad practice?

```
public class SomeClass{

  private final Strategy strategy;

  public void someMethod(){
   this.strategy = new Strategy();
   //call some strategy method to run an algorithm
    strategy.doSomeWork();
  }

  private class Strategy(){
    private doWork(){};
  }
}
```

**P.S**: `Strategy` does need access to the state of the `SomeClass`. So can't make it static.Another option is to have `Strategy` as an *interface* and then inject a concrete `Strategy` inside the `SomeClass` constructor but at the moment I do not see this particular `Strategy` interface being used by another class. So thought of the first approach. However,if I do take the first approach how would I have my class work seamlessly with multiple strategies?

Comment: Does the strategy need access to SomeClass? I think all inner classes should be static unless they need access to the parent class.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö See the edit.

Comment: It's not the strategy being used as another class that would be of benefit, but being able to switch out implementations of strategy without changing the class using it.

Comment: @BlackICE +1 for the comment. So you are suggesting an interface based implementation here right ?

Comment: absolutely, dependency injected interface

Comment: Which sort of implies the `Strategy` has to be static...

Comment: Does `Strategy` have to have state? could it be static and just accept an instance of `SomeClass`

Comment: @Austin Only requirement is that it should know about a couple of state parameters of `SomeClass` for running the algorithm.

Comment: @HannoBinder not sure I follow, how does that imply it has to be static

Comment: As you said, a strategy should be exchangeable and possibly compatible with a dependency injection scheme. This both, the latter more than the former, can only be sensibly used when instances of the strategy(-interface) can be created outside of the class in wich the basic strategy(-interface) is nested, and this seems to prohibit non-static nested classes for strategies.

Comment: @Hanno Not really; the class that uses them could also act as the factory of them, which would enable the use of non-static member classes just fine. Or they could be non-static members of another class. Or they could be anonymous classes. What you actually use depends on factors outside the immediate scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think your inner class strategy should be static because it must not work directly with the state of your class. This is how I think it should be done.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private final ExampleStrategy strategy;
    private int state;

    public ExampleClass(final int initialState, final ExampleStrategy strategy)
    {
        this.state = initialState;
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }


    public void useStrategy()
    {
        this.state = this.strategy.modifyState(this.state);
    }


    public static interface ExampleStrategy
    {
        int modifyState(final int state);
    }

    public static class IncrementStrategy implements ExampleStrategy
    {

        @Override
        public int modifyState(final int state)
        {
            return state + 1;
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        ExampleClass eClass = new ExampleClass(10, new IncrementStrategy());

        eClass.useStrategy();

    }
}
```